# How to deal with primitive obsession when using ORM like Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, orm, primitive-types

I do understand the goodness of creating whole value classes to encapsulate the specific domain ideas.

But how can I deal with it when the class/entity is persisted in database?

For example:

```
class User
{
   Email Email { get; set;}
   Address Address { get; set;}
   PhoneNumber CellPhone { get; set;}
   PhoneNumber HomePhone { get; set;}
}
```

SQL table to persist this data will contain columns of standard type (`nvarchar`);

If ORM generates the class from it, it will look like

```
class User
{
   string Email { get; set;}
   string Address { get; set;}
   string CellPhone { get; set;}
   string HomePhone { get; set;}
}
```

So, the question, what is the pattern that allows to use whole value and eliminate primitive obsession, but still store it using primitive types? And how do you make ORM to work properly with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity framework designer allows you to set the name and visibility of properties that are mapped from the database columns, so you can set the "primitive" properties to `private` and then declare wrapper properties that perform conversion.

Rough example:

```
// Class generated by entity framework designer
partial class User
{
    // Entity framework designer can be told to declare private properties
    // with custom "Db" names
    private string DbEmail { get; set; }      // Maps to Email column
    private string DbAddress { get; set; }    // Maps to Address column
    private string DbCellPhone { get; set; }  // Maps to CellPhone column
    private string DbHomePhone { get; set; }  // Maps to HomePhone column
}


// Class declared in User.cs
partial class User
{
    public Email Email
    {
        get { return new Email(DbEmail); }
        set { DbEmail = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public Address Address
    {
        get { return new Address(DbAddress); }
        set { DbAddress = value.ToString(); }
    }

    /* and so on...*/
}
```

Comment: But what if you're taking a code-first approach?   Can you use your custom type in your entities and expect the ORM to be able to work with it?

Answer (score 4):

Primitive Obsession is topic related to domain layer and not to persistence layer. When you have User class in your domain, Email should be represented as Value Object, but for persistence layer, you shouldn't use your domain objects, you need to have different User class, with Email property as primitive, then use Memento Pattern or automatic map library like AutoMapper to populate your persistence User class and store it. All this work should be done by your Generic/Specific Repository Class, because repository should be abstract consumers about persistence technology.

Domain/User.cs

```
public class User {
   //code omitted for brevity
   public EmailAddress Email { get; set; } //or protected set?
}
```

Persistence/User.cs

```
public class User {
       //code omitted for brevity
       public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Repository/UserRepository.cs

```
public class UserRepository {

   //code omitted for brevity

   public void Save(Domain.User user) {
      //Pseudo-code
      //1) Validate Domain.User
      //2) Convert Domain.User to Persistence.User
      //3) Persist Persistence.User
   }
}
```

A last comment: you can simplify your conversion if your overload conversion operators on EmailAddress class, so you can cast it to string without worry too much about it.

Comment: Memento pattern? There's no need for an undo/rollback mechanism here.

Comment: Isn't about undo/rollback only persist/restore state of the object. Memento could be useful here, but I prefer the mapping strategy.